# Read and compare vs Rewrite efficiency in C#

Tags: performance, time-complexity, processing-efficiency

The question is, is it more efficient to rewrite a variable than to read an compare it?

Lets say you have the following codes:

Code 1

```
int x = 0;

for( int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++ )
{
    x = 333;
}
```

Code 2

```
int x = 0;

for( int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++ )
{
    if( x != 333 )    
        x = 333;
}
```

Which code is more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

Both the read and the write will take one processor cycle (or, even less, depending on processor architecture):  so the second option is slightly, slightly less "efficient" because it will result in 200,001 operations (100,000 increments, 100,000 compares, and one assignment) than the first, which will do 200,000 operations (100,000 increments, and 100,000 assignments).

There's a rub though.  Your compiler will probably recognize the pointlessness of the first loop, and optimize  it to a single assignment of  333 to the variable x.   It will eliminate the loop entirely, along with  the repeated identical assignments.   So, instead of 200,000 operations, or 200,001, there will be one.

Comment: Thanks! When I wrote the question I was thinking about a more complex problem, say guaranteeing that a objet has certain values at all time even if they are changed by another routine. The problem is that the other routine is someone elses code so the problem is not trivial.